# Recode Date (time) varibre in to new discrete variable

Tags: r

i have time variable :   `"00:00:29","00:06:39","20:43:15"....`
and I want to recode to new vector  - time based work shifts:

```
07:00:00 - 13:00:00   -  1 
13:00:00 - 20:00:00   -  2
23:00:00 - 7:00:00    -  3
```

thanks for any idea :)

Comment: What have you already tried? And why did it not work?

Comment: I do not know how to do it, I'm a novice in r.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the time variables are strings as shown, this seems to work:

```
secNr <- function(x){ sum(as.numeric(unlist(strsplit(x,":",fixed=TRUE))) * c(3600,60,1)) }

workShift <- function(x)
{
  n <- which.max(secNr(x) >= c(secNr("23:00:00"),secNr("20:00:00"),secNr("13:00:00"),secNr("07:00:00"),secNr("00:00:00")))
  c(3,NA,2,1,3)[n]
}
```

"workShift" computes the work shift of *one* such time string. If you have a vector of time strings, use "sapply". Example:

```
> Time <- sprintf("%i:%02i:00", 0:23, sample(0:59,24))

> Shift <- sapply(Time,"workShift")

> Shift
 0:37:00  1:17:00  2:35:00  3:09:00  4:08:00  5:28:00  6:03:00  7:43:00  8:27:00  9:38:00 10:48:00 11:50:00 12:58:00 13:32:00 14:05:00 15:39:00 16:56:00 
       3        3        3        3        3        3        3        1        1        1        1        1        1        2        2        2        2 
17:00:00 18:22:00 19:02:00 20:42:00 21:11:00 22:15:00 23:01:00 
       2        2        2       NA       NA       NA        3
```